# How to access the windows VM via lan?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7, virtual-machines

I want to access windows VM via lan, but the problem is that I do not have any lan setup. I have my laptop and it is running on Windows 7. I have Windows VM of Windows Server 2008 on the laptop. Now I want to access the Website I have hosted in the IIS of VM on my laptop. How to do it?

Kindly note that I DO NOT have any lan network, it is a standalone system.

Kindly help.

Comment: Virtual PC or some other virtualisation tool?

Comment: Windows Virtual PC

Answer (score 3):

You create a virtual network and communicate from your host to your guests over it.

Comment: Kindly share a link to how to do it ? I am using Windows Virtual PC.

Comment: ["Networking in Virtual PC and Virtual Server"](http://ixbtlabs.com/articles2/cm/virtualization-vpc-vserv-page1.html)